Opentelemetry Collector attributeprocessor not inserting attributes from other attributes
I'm trying to use the Opentelemetry Collector attributeprocessor to write a "hostname" attribute from the journald receiver _HOSTNAME attribute so that the json output will have a field "hostname" in it containing the name/value pair for the hostname and also use the new value as a label.
Other than it not working, the challenge is also getting debug information, enabling debug logging doesn't show me the processing of my rules. There is no error, if a rule doesn't match it's skipped.
The fields I'm trying to process are nested under a body element so what I've been trying to do is to change the "from_attribute" to all the possible values I think could be valid body__hostname, body._HOSTNAME, _HOSTNAME for example don't work.
This is the collector configuration:
receivers:
  journald:

processors:
  resource:
    attributes:
    - action: insert
      key: loki.format
      value: json
    - action: insert
      key: environment
      value: dev
    - action: insert
      key: loki.attribute.labels
      value: hostname, priority
  attributes:
    actions:
      - action: insert
        key: hostname
        from_attribute: _HOSTNAME
      - action: insert
        key: priority
        from_attribute: PRIORITY

exporters:
  loki:
    endpoint: xxxx
    sending_queue:
      num_consumers: 10
      queue_size: 50000
    headers:
      "X-Scope-OrgID": "xxxx"
    tls:
      ca_file: xxxx
      cert_file: xxxx
      key_file: xxxx

service:
  pipelines:
    logs:
      receivers: [journald]
      processors: [attributes,resource]
      exporters: [loki]


And here is my message in Grafana showing the _HOSTNAME field nested under the body element along with all the other fields:


Question answered on the opentelemetry project github page
